# Prove that $\lim_{x \to 4^-}\frac{x-2}{x(x-4)} = -\infty$

Tags: limits, functions

I'm trying to prove that $\lim_{x \to 4^-}\frac{x-2}{x(x-4)} = -\infty$.

Can I say that when that when the radius of the enviorment is small enough, $x\neq 0$, and therefore I can say that:

$\frac{x-2}{x(x-4)} = \frac{1-\frac{2}{x}}{x-4}$

and so,  $\lim_{x \to 4^-} \frac{1-\frac{2}{x}}{x-4} = -\infty$ ?

Is there a better way to prove it?

Comment: What sort of class or level of math is this for?

Comment: Are you familiar with these relations: $$\forall \,N>0\,\exists \,\delta >0:\,\,0<4-x<\delta \Rightarrow \,\frac{x-2}{x(x-4)}<-N$$

Comment: Yes I'm familiar with the $\epsilon, \delta$ definition

Comment: then you can use these.

Comment: Your proof is correct. You can also write  $$\frac{x-2}{x(x-4)}=\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{2(x-4)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is good, but if you need a proof on first principles, you need some more details.

Fix $M>0$; you want to find $\delta>0$ such that, for $4-\delta<x<4$, you have
$$
\frac{x-2}{x(x-4)}<-M
$$
or, as you write,
$$
\frac{1-\frac{2}{x}}{x-4}<-M
$$
We can assume $2<x<4$, so $0<1-\frac{2}{x}<\frac{1}{2}$.

So we have
$$
\frac{1-\frac{2}{x}}{x-4}<\frac{1/2}{x-4}
$$
and we just need $\frac{1/2}{x-4}<-M$, that is,
$$
x-4>-\frac{1}{2M}
$$
so we can take
$$
\delta=\min\left\{2,\frac{1}{2M}\right\}
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is only true if
$x \to 4$ from below.
If $x >4$ then
$x-4>0$ so the limit is
$+\infty$.